# Raspberry Pi modem connection

Tags: raspbian, networking, putty

I have a wifi modem/router. it has lan ports also. I want to connect my raspberry pi to the modem using Ethernet cable and I want to operate raspberry pi using putty in my laptop which is connected to the same modem using wifi. How to do it ? How do i get the ip of the raspberry pi so that i can use putty?

Comment: what make/model router? It should have an admin page you can view that will list connected devices. Alternately run nmap to find your Pi http://jumpstation.co.uk/flog/Jan2013.html#190120131001

Comment: currently i have connected to my laptop using ethernet cable so i have assigned an ip 169.xxx.xxx.xxx. Should I remove it?

Comment: If you have given the Pi a static IP address then you just need to make sure you are using the IP address range on the device you wish to connect with. 169.xxx.xxx.xxx addresses are Windows default when no DHCP server is available. Try and set your router as DHCP server to avoid this. Otherwise you will have to set everything manually.

Comment: my modem will assign ip from 192.168.1.xxx. So i need to change that assigned ip to any manual ip which will be assigned by modem?

Comment: When setup correctly the router should give the Pi an IP address from the DHCP pool, which looks from your comment as being in the 192.168.1.xxx range. Remove any manual setting on the Pi and it will get the value from DHCP. Then either use external display and keyboard to the get the IP address or use a tool like nmap if your router does not have a "connected devices" type page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:** Install a network scanner like Fing (free on iOS and Android), scan your WiFi and look for the hostname raspberrypi -- the ip next to it is the one you need.

**Method 2:** Depending on your router's (DNS) configuration, you may also be able to use the hostname in PuttY instead of the ip. The standard hostname is "raspberrypi" so you can simply try that or "raspberrypi.local".

P.S.: No explicit need to assign a static ip. Many routers keep giving the same ip to the same device as long as the DHCP address pool is not exhausted (e.g. by many wifi users). I'm running a similar setup and the Raspberry's ip hasn't changed in weeks even though it and the router were rebooted many times.